IRS tax credit for used EVs
IRS website mentions that the AGI should be less than 150k$ for married couple to qualify for EV tax credit. Form the website

You can use your modified AGI from the year you take delivery of the vehicle or the year before, whichever is less. If your income is below the threshold for 1 of the 2 years, you can claim the credit.

I have moved to the US in 2024 and hence my income from 2023 is 0. Will I be eligible for the tax rebate?

For those not familiar with it -- I wasn't -- https://www.irs.gov/credits-deductions/used-clean-vehicle-credit
